# Calling a predefined function with void* parameter

Tags: c, function, parameter-passing

I have a function `func1` with the signature

```
int func1(struct a *a1, int b1, const enum c c1);
```

I want to call this function using another predefined function with the signature

```
void callerfunc(void (*func)(void *params), void *params);
```

Note that I cannot modify the above two functions.

To do so, I considered making a new struct pointed to by `params` which can then be used with a wrapper function to call `func1`, i.e.

```
struct param_holder {
     struct a a1;
     int b1;
     enum c c1;
};

int wrapper_func1(void* params) { // params points to initialized struct
    return func1(params->a1, params->b1, params->c1);
}
```

I would like to know if there is a different or better way of achieving this, possibly without creating the wrapper function. Thanks!

Comment: Given your constraints the wrapper function is probably the least bad option available to you. It's a common idiom when dealing with things like multi-threading APIs.

Comment: [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is maybe a better place for your question.

Comment: @nouney will keep that in mind for next time, thanks.

Comment: Did you mean `void wrapper_func1` ? Otherwise this doesn't match your stated signature.

Comment: True. Using void will imply that I cannot return `func1`s return value, which I will have to compromise?.

Comment: You also need to pass a `struct a *` as the first parameter, rather than a `struct a` as `wrapper_func1` is doing.

Comment: You can put the function return value in an additional field in `struct param_holder`.

Answer (score 2):

Using wrapper is a good solution to me. Just cast before using void pointer :

```
int wrapper_func1(void* void_params) { // params points to initialized struct
    struct param_holder *params = (struct param_holder *) void_params;
    return func1(params->a1, params->b1, params->c1);
}
```

Comment: Woops, I meant to, but forgot casting in the snippet above. Thank you.

Comment: This cast is redundant; there is implicit conversion from `void *`